# Toggle Desaturation on image onClick in css / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prototype, image

There is more code to each function, but these are the main lines that matter in regards to my question I believe...This is from a guys library to desaturate an image on rollover basically.

How do I change it to on click, rather than on mouseover / rollover? Here's his code...

```
jQuery(function($){
$cloned.closest(".DesaturateDiv").bind("mouseenter mouseleave",desevent);
}

  function desevent(event) 
  {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter')
         $(".des.color", this).fadeOut(275);

    if (event.type == 'mouseleave')
        $(".des.color", this).fadeIn(200);
  }
```

I've already tried changing both if statements to a jquery toggle as well as changing the top line from .bind("mouseenter mouseleave", desevent) ... to .bind("toggle", desevent) and it still didnt work. my question is basically how to substitute mouseenter and mouseleave to onClick so the image desaturates onClick then saturates again onClick. Heres my toggle code that I put in instead of the two if's above, just incase.

```
$('.DesaturateDiv').toggle(function() {

$(".des.color", this).fadeOut(275);

}, function() {
$(".des.color", this).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Also, on a related note, could you do this with css3? 
here's the code to desaturate an image with css3...

```
 img.desaturate{
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%); -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

So my question would be how to do it oncick?

I tried img.desaturate:active{} but it didn't work?

EDIT: I tried this and think something along these lines is what I need but im sure the syntax is not correct, help??

```
 function desevent(event) 
  {
    i = 0;

    if( i = 0 ){
    if (event.type == 'mousedown')
         $(".des.color", this).fadeOut(275);
         i = 1;
    }

    if( i = 1 ){
    if (event.type == 'mousedown')
        $(".des.color", this).fadeIn(200);
                     i = 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: use http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imagefx/ javascript library instead

Comment: thanks that library looks good. The desaturate button works, but im not sure how to get it to saturate back onClick and back again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a specific class to the clicked element.

```
.desaturate{
    transition-duration: 400ms; //and other prefixes
}
.desaturate.active{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Comment: wouldnt it have to be :active, not .active? I already tried that but wont work.

Comment: It can be because of some incorrect line in your CSS. Just try it in one browser and, when it works, start adding another styles.